# Optimizing java for multiple screens and resolutions

Tags: java, lwjgl, resolution, slick2d

Hello I am creating a 2D RPG game in my free time and I have been mostly working on it from my laptop but when I brought it to school to work on it it crashes and gives me the error in the eclipse console:

```
org.newdawn.slick.SlickException: Failed to find value mode: 1366x768 fs=true
          at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.setDisplayMode(AppGameContainer.java:146)
          at com.states.Core.main(Core.java:49)
```

The resolution i have been using is WIDTH = 1366, HEIGHT = 768 please let me know if there are better ones and thank you to the ones that can help

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452784/java-and-libgdx-lwjgl-game-fullscreen-wrong-size-for-multiple-monitors-on-ubun

Answer (score 1):

This bit of code will give you the usable screen width and height on any system.

```
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class ScreenResolution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rectangle r = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
                .getMaximumWindowBounds();
        System.out.println(r);
    }

}
```

On my system the result is:

```
java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=1280,height=984]
```

The GraphicsEnvironment class gives you information about fonts and screen devices.